# Keeping websites within an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, twitter

Certain websites like Twitter, Flickr, etc avoid being stuck within an iframe. Is there any way to stop this from happening? I just need to see the public data so I am open to disabling Javascript, etc. How do I disable Javascript running on the iframe? Is this possible?

Comment: As a user or a developer of the page you're trying to trap, I would strongly considering hunting you down and sticking *you* in a frame for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't disable JavaScript on iFrames or any other resources AFAIK.

The only way to reliably do this is to load the sites through a proxy PHP or other server-side script, filter out any JavaScript (which will break many sites), and fix all relative references to images and other media - a task that would take an insane amount of time to complete if you want the sites to actually work.

If you just need some data from the sites, proxying might work. Seeing as the Same Origin Policy would prevent you getting anything from an IFRAME from a different domain anyway, it is also the only way to access content on those sites using JavaScript.

Comment: This is the method that I finally chose to use. Also, using onbeforeunload you will be able to detect the sites that want to break out.

Answer (score 1):

In IE only, there is the [`<iframe security="restricted">`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534622%28VS.85%29.aspx) attribute. This disables JavaScript in the targeted document, which would break a JS frame-escape script — along with all other interaction that's script-dependent.

However, apart from the browser compatibility issue, it's very rude to frame a site that doesn't want to be framed, and it will work less and less anyway as more sites deploy [`X-Frame-Options`](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2010/03/30/Combating-ClickJacking-with-X-Frame-Options.aspx).

I'm not sure what you mean by “need to see the public data”... as Pekka said, you won't be able to ‘see’ into an iframe's DOM from outside it, as that would be a security problem.